# Python Curses Refreshing Text With a Loop

Tags: python, ncurses, python-curses

I'm connecting via Linux Mint's Xfce terminal ssh (also tried ssh -t) to a Raspberry Pi running Rasperian Stretch. On the Pi I have a Python-Curses example which I modified trying to get the current time to update every few seconds "in place" over writing  itself. But it prints the time once initially and then never prints an updated time. But if I manually press "Enter" key on my laptop the time updates, if I press "Enter" fast multiple times the "enters" stack-up and the time shows updates for as many times as I pressed enter. There's probably something maybe basic I don't understand about Curses and  terminals or Python in this case. Appreciate it. Here's code:

```
import curses
import traceback
import datetime
import time

try:
    # -- Initialize --
    stdscr = curses.initscr()   # initialize curses screen
    curses.noecho()             # turn off auto echoing of keypress on to screen
    curses.cbreak()             # enter break mode where pressing Enter key
                                #  after keystroke is not required for it to register
    stdscr.keypad(1)            # enable special Key values such as curses.KEY_LEFT etc

    # -- Perform an action with Screen --
    stdscr.border(0)
    stdscr.addstr(5, 5, 'Hello from Curses!', curses.A_BOLD)
    stdscr.addstr(6, 5, 'Press q to close this screen', curses.A_NORMAL)

    while True:
        # stay in this loop till the user presses 'q'
        #stdscr.addstr(7, 5, 'zztop',curses.A_NORMAL)
        ti = str((datetime.datetime.now().time()))
        stdscr.addstr(8, 5, 'Time: '+ ti, curses.A_NORMAL)
        time.sleep(3)

        ch = stdscr.getch()
        if ch == ord('q'):
            break



    # -- End of user code --

except:
    traceback.print_exc()     # print trace back log of the error

finally:
    # --- Cleanup on exit ---
    stdscr.keypad(0)
    curses.echo()
    curses.nocbreak()
    curses.endwin()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `stdscr.refresh()` before sleeping to flush output to the screen.

You may also want to add `stdscr.nodelay(1)` to the initialization sequence in your program (i.e, right below `stdscr.keypad(1)`). This will make calls to `stdscr.getch()` non-blocking. Alternatively, you can call `stdscr.timeout(3000)` instead and remove the call to `sleep` entirely.

Comment: stdscr.refresh() and stdscr.nodelay(1) added and it works like I wanted it to. Will have read-up about "non-blocking" stdscr.getch() calls. Thanks for the help, you fixed it.